# tar not archiving all my files

Tags: macos, tar

I wanted to test some potential destructive code on a directory and all its subdirectories.  So, I tarballed it and then made a copy from the tarball in a space where my code wouldn't accidentally obliterate anything that I really wanted to keep.  My code seemed to work except that I noticed that certain files were not put into the tarball.

This is what I originally did:

```
 tar -czf mydirectory.tar.gz directory
```

In the *safe location* I then did the following:

```
 tar -xzf mydirectory.tar.gz
```

I ran a recursive `diff` on the archived and original directories.  This showed that certain files where missing.

It seems that any file named `.__<name>__` were not recorded in the archive.  For example, `.__quiz__` or `.__example__`.

What is `tar` skipping over these files?  How do I get `tar` to include them?  What other files might `tar` not record?

Even if I ran `tar` in *verbose mode*, there was no message that things were being skipped over.

**UPDATE**

I installed the `gnu` version of `tar`.  That works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, for me tar archives all the files with this pattern `.__<file>__` unless I put the pattern in `-exclude=` option.

Can you input `echo $TAR_OPTIONS` in your shell and see if it is set? Perhaps you have some default options set for tar (like the above exclude pattern).

Edit:

So, tar ignores `.__<name>__` files judging by your verbose tar output.
Is it perhaps aliased to exclude that pattern? Type `alias` to list all aliased commands.

Comment: The `$TAR_OPTIONS` variable doesn't appear to be set:  at least when I try `echo $TAR_OPTIONS`.

Comment: Hmm, do you have `COPYFILE_DIABLE` variable set? If it's set to true it should block any file starting with `._`

Comment: No.  That also is not set.

Comment: But I don't seem to have a problem with Mac OS creating at `._<name>` files like some people here have complained about: though I don't have a non-Mac machine to test that out on.  Maybe Mac is hiding them from me.

Comment: Well, `ls -al` should list them if they aren't shown regularly.

Comment: Yeah.  Everything I do is within a terminal.  `ls -al` doesn't show them.  But `tar` isn't creating them either:  even when I open the tar ball in `emacs`, I don't see these `._<name>` files others have complained about.

Comment: "Even if I ran tar in verbose mode, there was no message that things were being skipped over." If I understood correctly, this means that in verbose mode you do get messages `.__<file>__` are included?

Comment: No.  In verbose mode `.__<file>__` are also not included.  I just meant that I didn't get a warning like `unable to archive .__<file>__` or some other kind of warning to indicate that something's been skipped over.